# Почему у меня не получается программировать?

Tags: веб-программирование

Всем привет! Я занимаюсь программированием уже 3 месяц, программирую на JS. И у меня такая ситуация, я сейчас прохожу курсы по JS, и там дается ДЗ по темам, и вот у меня не получается хорошо программировать, ДЗ которые они дают для меня сложно(т.е. я выполняю 30-50% ДЗ а дальше всё, я не могу программировать дальше, у меня не получается). Вопрос: вначале у всеми так сложно бывает или только у меня?

Comment: Ну ничего. Трудности обычно появляются при изучении чего-то нового.. просто не бойтесь пройти этот порог. ☝️

Comment: Трудности у всех бывают. Это как протаптывание тропинок в глубоком снегу. Там где уже вытоптано, там ходить просто, а чуть в сторону - и глубокий снег, ой как тяжело идти.

Comment: Не у всех есть способности к тому или иному делу! НО если долго мучиться, то что-нибудь получится! Времени может больше понадобиться, но базовые знания доступны каждому ;)

Comment: А у вас тоже так было?

Comment: @yozhikk, вы "устаёте"? У людей, которые нашли себе новое хобби,  может проявляться так называемая "усталость". Вы, наверное, слишком много кодите. Нужно отвлечься...

Comment: https://twitter.com/__coding_tips__